# How to properly bind objects, like gallery to SharePoint lookup columns?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-selected-items

I have list with a `lookup column` linked to another list on SharePoint Online. Like there's list of tours and I would like to assign transport vehicles (eg bus) to each of them. When I let PowerApps generate an app from the list, the lookup column is converted to a dropdown list with multi-select option.

I would like to show the vehicle details in a gallery, but when I bind the items of the gallery to the `bus` field of the main list, I get a list of all vehicles, regardless which and how many is selected.

When I bind the items to the selected items of the dropdown list like `cb_bus.Selected`, however, I see the correct items. So, as a workaround, I could hide this dropdown and show only the gallery, but I hope there's a more straightforward way to present this field.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it out with lookup fields, the steps sound corrent. I used "Choice" function which only gives back id and value. To display details of selected, I need to bind with the list containing detials.

Comment: I was a little afraid of that. To display, I can live with a hidden combo box, but can I manipulate the selected items from another control? (add / remove object to the lookup field's selected value) Or the is combo box control the only one that is able to do this currently? I was happy in the beginning that I could achieve a one to many relationship here without extra lists, but this looks like a dead end.